# how can i make fabric.js save the state/ position of each object in canvas for the future purpose of editing the canvas object

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I have to make the editor it contains the object like image and text etc, I want to save the state of all active object in canvas for purpose of future editing.

Comment: Use `toJSON` and `loadfromjson`

Comment: I think it is **toDatalessJSON** instead of **toJSON**

Comment: if you are using `toDatalessJSON`, it wont includes all the basic `properties`